# htdocs permissions issue with XAMPP

Tags: php

When I am saving something as a php file in htdocs for xampp it gives me this error

The document “Untitled” could not be saved as “index.php”. You do not have appropriate access privileges.

The system is a Mac machine.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have the necessary permissions to save in the directory.  You will need to talk to your system admin about that.

Comment: He is using xampp. And in the title he is talking about "localhost". So it looks like he is his own admin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in shared server, may be you have assigned a sub-directory under htdocs, so try to save your file in different directory or check your administrator to witch directory you granted.

Comment: I doubt he's on a shared server if he's using XAMPP.

Comment: There who use XAMPP, XAMPP isn't limited for localhost, may be a company or a small network.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer you gave to Felipe Almeida I see that you have a permission problem on your mac. Apple has a good [Knowledge Base article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2963) about this. After you have read this you should be able to solve your problem. They have pictures where you can see what you have to click. (You have to read from the chapter "Permissions Defined" on. The beginning is not of interest for you.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found on some installs, the whole tree of folders is read only. HTdocs is in a folder. Check to see if that is read only.